# C# initialize class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating wpf application in vs2010. I have a simple question.

I have a class to display image:

```
private void displayImage()
{
     newImage.Width = 900;
     newImage.Height = 700;

     BitmapImage testim = new BitmapImage();
     testim.BeginInit();
     testim.UriSource = new Uri("E:\\WpfApplication1\\Images\\test.jpg");
     testim.EndInit();

     newImage.Source = testim;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Image Name="newImage" ImageFailed="newImage_ImageFailed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

To initialize it, I call `displayImage();` from another class.

I want this image to be visible as soon as I run the application. I want to how to initialize it without calling it from another class?

Thanks a lot.

regards

Comment: It doesn't appear that you use the "t" anywhere. Why is it there?

Comment: First the bool has nothing to do with the initialization, second you're not even using it.

Comment: in another class, I call displayImage(true), and I can see the image. I can get rid of bool. I want to know how to initialize it without calling it.

Comment: You have no logic driven off of that bool, you don't need it.

Comment: Like what others said but in different words: When you call `displayImage`, you require to enter a `bool` named `t`. But you don't use that `t` anywhere else in your code. So why do you need `t`?

Comment: From what i'm seeing, you have no reason to be using the code behind. You could do everything you're doing in the XAML

Comment: no, its just test image, my original image will be output of another process. I am just clearing my concepts on Image class.

Comment: questions edited. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: What is happening? Doesn't it work? What do you see?

Comment: it works, but I want that image to displayed as soon as I run my application. Now, I click a button that initialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure why you try to set it in code. It is easier to set this in XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Image Name="newImage" ImageFailed="newImage_ImageFailed" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="900" 
                           Height="700" Margin="10" Source="/Images/test.jpg" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

The above should already do the trick. Note that I've also set the `Width` and `Height` values for the image. No code is needed to achieve this.

And if you really want to set the image in the code on start, you need to be in the constructor of the WPF page/window. The constructor of a class gets called when the class is being created. In this case when the Window or Page needs to be created, the first thing your application does is calling the constructor. In this constructor, the application also learns that some graphical stuff has to be built. That's how constructors work.

After `InitializeComponent();`, you can put in whatever you like. For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Page
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displayImage();
    }

    private void displayImage()
    {
        newImage.Width = 900;
        newImage.Height = 700;

        BitmapImage testim = new BitmapImage();
        testim.BeginInit();
        testim.UriSource = new Uri("E:\\WpfApplication1\\Images\\test.jpg");
        testim.EndInit();

        newImage.Source = testim;
    }
}
```

If the path is going to be dynamic, binding your image is the best practice. In your XAML, have something like:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

So the UriSource gets bound to your `ImagePath`. In the code, have the following:

```
public BitmapImage ImagePath
{ get { return testim; } }
```

So it gets bound to that. If you change the value, the binding makes sure the value in the GUI changes with it.

Comment: adding after InitializeComponent(); is what I was looking for. thanks. As I said this is test part about how to use things. The source of image needs to set dynamically. I think that is easy to set in the code not XAML.

Comment: @Naresh I've added some more in my answer. If your source will be dynamic, you'll have to teach yourself how to bind datasources. That'll make things so much easier and is one of the actual strenghts and advantages of using WPF instead of Windows Forms.

Comment: perfect. I just needed to know what to look for. I am new to c# and there is so much information, i feel lost. I will read up. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Naresh I've started with nothing 5 months ago on an internship and continue to learn every day here. I still feel there is so much more to learn but if things catch on, it's a fun ride! ;) Good luck!

Comment: @Naresh I've changed my answer one last time, explaining more about constructors in the beginning of my post. You might be interested in that. Now I'll leave this question alone.