# Image creation in model

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I am having trouble creating a model which also displays a pic,

my model class:

```
   public class City
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Image Country
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

then in my mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
List<City> source = new List<City>();
 BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/PhoneApp7;component/Images/test.png",    UriKind.Relative));
        City new_city = new City();

        new_city.Name = "Africa";
        new_city.Country.Source = bi;
        new_city.Language = "xhosa";

        source.Add(new_city);

        citiesList.ItemsSource = source;
```

I get a nullreference exception, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and is there perhaps another way of adding an image to a source for databinding?

---

I have tried this:

```
 public class City
{
    public City(Uri countryUri)
    {
        Country = new BitmapImage(countryUri);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public BitmapImage Country
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Language
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

app.xaml:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="citiesItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="26"  Margin="12,-12,12,6"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Country}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Language}" Foreground="Orange" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

mainpage.xaml

```
  List<City> source = new List<City>();

        Uri bi = new Uri("/Images/test.png", UriKind.Relative);
        City new_city = new City(bi) { Name = "Africa", Language = "xhosa", };

        new_city.Name = "Africa";
        new_city.Language = "Xhosa";

        source.Add(new_city);

        citiesList.ItemsSource = source;
```

mainpage.xaml:

```
  <phone:LongListSelector  x:Name="citiesList"  
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 ItemTemplate="{Binding citiesItemTemplate}"
                                 />
```

but now where the image is suppose to display, it only shows phoneapp7.Model.City, not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to instantiate `Country` before using it (i.e. `new_city.Country.Source = bi;`). E.g.: `new_city.Country = new Image(someArgsIfAny)`

Answer (score 1):

Your model should not have a property of type `Image`, because `Image` is a control, which belongs to the view. Change it into something like this:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Country { get; set; }
}
```

and then assign the property like this:

```
new_city.Country = bi;
```

---

You may also just use the image URL in your model:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Country { get; set; }
}

new_city.Country = new Uri(...);
```

---

In either case you would have an `Image` control in your view that has it's `Source` property bound to the model:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Country}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you would have a null reference exception since you didn't initialize your image and tried to access one of its properties.

in the model use BitmapImage in place of image.

then in the xaml in the template create Image control and bind it with the property Country

check the answer in here [C# initialize class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918628/c-sharp-initialize-class)